# How to extract a particular column in python dataframe with Max values

Tags: python, pandas

I have just begun using python and m stuck at a very basic question. I have already looked  at the similar questions that were posted but unfortunately I am still struggling to get the right answer.

I have a promotional data with the a lot of variables such as unit price , product name

All I want to do is to find the most expensive product using the unit price column

The syntax I am using is

Stores['unit price'].max

Which is giving me the the maximum uni price , now how do I find the product name correspondence to this unit price. Basically I want to extract the correspondening product with this price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for index from column `product name` and [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for `product name` by max value of column `unit price`:

```
a = Stores.set_index('product name')['unit price'].idxmax()
```

**Sample**:

```
Stores = pd.DataFrame({'product name':['a','b','c'], 'unit price':[3,8,6]})
print (Stores)
  product name  unit price
0            a           3
1            b           8
2            c           6

a = Stores.set_index('product name')['unit price'].idxmax()
print (a)
b
```

Comment: Thank you, it did work for me but can you also suggest how can I just indicate python to select only one column using the method I was earlier using

Comment: Not sure if understand, can you explain more?

Comment: sure, All I mean is that based off any condition given to me how can I extract a single column from the data.

Comment: What if I want to use another condition like finding the minimum price and then corresponding order I'd
 What should be the syntx for that @jezrael

Comment: Then use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - here `df = df[df['unit price'] == df['unit price'].max()]` or `df = df[df['unit price'] > 100]`

Comment: And for minimum is possible use `Stores.set_index('product name')['unit price'].idxmin()`

Comment: Or `df = df.loc[df['unit price'] == df['unit price'].min(), 'product name']`

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael! :)